# Spring shell prompt prints different things when run from a LaunchAgent or manually

Tags: macos-ventura, spring-shell, launch-agent

I have a JAR file (authentication.jar) that is using `org.springframework.shell` to provide a simple console to generate tokens. In there is defined a custom `PromptProvider`:

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomPromptProvider implements PromptProvider {
    private final SessionService sessionService;

    @Override
    public AttributedString getPrompt() {

        String prompt;
        if (sessionService.isLogged()) {
            prompt = "[" + sessionService.getServerName() + "] " + sessionService.getUsername() + ">";
        } else if (sessionService.isConnected()) {
            prompt = "[" + sessionService.getServerName() + "]>";
        } else {
            prompt = "auth-shell>";
        }
        return new AttributedString(prompt);
    }

}
```

I have created a scenario for expect to start authentication.jar, wait for the prompt to appear, and execute certain commands to automate getting a token. It first waits to see "auth-shell>", connects to the server, waits to see the server name in the prompt, then logs the user.

I made a small bash script that calls the expect scenario with parameters defined in the script, if I ever want to quickly and manually generate a token.

Finally, I created a NodeJS server to allow queries to localhost:3737 to generate tokens: the web server listens for the required info, then runs the expect script, and retrieves the token output that way.

Now, when I run any of the scripts (the JAR file, the expect scenario, the bash script, or the NodeJS server), I get a token without any issue. However, I cannot generate a token when I try to make a LaunchAgent daemon to do it for me.

I am using a MacBook Pro with the M1 chip, and so wish for my NodeJS server to be started at boot. I looked into it, and have made the following file in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>node_token_generator</string>

    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>

    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>

    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/node_token_generator.log</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/node_token_generator.log</string>

    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/sh</string>
        <string>-i</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/node "$HOME/.local/lib/node_token_generator.js"</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The NodeJS server starts properly, and I can see logs in the log file. However, when I try to generate a token by calling localhost:3737, I get an error. Looking into the log file, I see that instead of printing the expected prompts (e.g. "auth-shell>"), it prints `ESC[?2004h>....`. Here's an example:

- Logs of authentication.jar when NodeJS server run manually:

  ```
  auth-shell>connect --server <url> --port <port>
  Server greetings [Application <app> is running]
  Connected to [<url>:<port>]
  [<url>]>activedirectory --username <username>
  AD password for [<user>] : ************
  Your token [<token>]
  ```
- Logs of authentication.jar when NodeJS server run through LaunchAgent:

  ```
  ESC[?2004h>....Server greetings [Application <app> is running]
  Connected to [<url>:<port>]
  ESC[?2004h>....
  ```

I tried on another Macbook Pro, but to no avail. Running the server manually makes the prompt appear properly, and environment variables do not seem to be the issue: running the script manually with only `$HOME` set still works.

I cloned the authentication.jar repo and put a print in the method that returns the prompt, and I can see that the variable **does** hold the correct value, but for some reason it is not printed.

Is there any difference in how the LaunchAgent starts the script? sets up its environment? Is there a known bug in the shell provided by Spring?